# javafx.geometry.Point2D -- Make it serializable

Tags: serialization, geometry, javafx-2

I currently noticed that the javafx.geometry.Point2D is not serializable.
Is there any way I can implement the interface myself for this class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Point2D.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it by inheritance, because javafx.geometry.Point2D does not provide a no-arg constructor. You could do it by composition, as follows. That may be inconvenient because of the getPoint() method, the alternative being to reproduce any of the Point2D interface that you need. When I encountered this, I simply used java.awt.Point2D.Double instead, which is Serializable, but of course doesn't have the rich interface of javafx.geometry.Point2D.

```
class MyPoint2DByComposition implements Serializable {
   Point2D myPoint ;

   public MyPoint2DByComposition(double x, double y) {
      myPoint = new Point2D(x,y) ;
   }

   public Point2D getPoint() {
      return myPoint ;
   }

   private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) 
   throws IOException {
      out.writeDouble(myPoint.getX());
      out.writeDouble(myPoint.getY());
   }

   private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
   throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
      myPoint = new Point2D(in.readDouble(), in.readDouble()) ;         
   }
}
```